# How to use Scalaz 7's EitherT with liftM

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

If I have a monad transformer type taking two type arguments, I can use `liftM` to lift values into the transformed monad:

```
scala> val o = 1.point[List].liftM[OptionT]
o: scalaz.OptionT[List,Int] = OptionT(List(Some(1)))
```

However if I try the same thing with `EitherT` it seems like I must use a type alias (or a type lambda):

```
scala> val e = 1.point[List].liftM[({type l[a[+_],b] = EitherT[a, String, b]})#l]
e: scalaz.EitherT[List,java.lang.String,Int] = scalaz.EitherTFunctions$$anon$14@3f8905ca
```

What's the proper way to do this? Ideally inferring the type argument for `liftM` using the expected type of the expression (something like `val blah: EitherT[List, String, Int] = 1.point[List].liftM`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a better way to handle multi-argument type constructors in general, but in the specific case of `EitherT`, we can use `EitherT.right`:

```
scala> val o: EitherT[List, String, Int] = EitherT.right(1.point[List])
o: scalaz.EitherT[List,String,Int] = scalaz.EitherTFunctions$$anon$14@12fa8880
```